# Does mongoose filter out extra properties?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm about to work on a new app. And we've decided to use mongo as our db for quick prototyping along with mongoose for an orm. My question is, after declaring a new model. When I try to save a new model will it filter out extra keys? For example. Let's say a model has one property `name`. Will the model ignore extra keys?

```
let user = new User({
  name:"bob",
  randomKey: ""
}); 

user.save();
```

The reason is because I want to be able to do this in an express controller.

```
let user = new User({ ...req.body});
user.save();
```

Or in cases where a schema has many props.

Answer (score 3):

This is now a breaking change in v4.13.19. ( atleast onwards v4.13.19)

You can now only -

1. Save fields described in schema ( strict : true)
2. Or make strict : false, and allow anything to be saved.

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4801

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `mongoose` doesn't save the fields that are not present on the schema definition.

**Student schema:-**

```
var Student = mongoose.model('Student', { name: String, event : String });
```

**Post request:-**

```
{
    "name" : "extra fields",
    "event" : "from postman",
    "event2" : "not on schema"
}
```

**Collection:-**

The `event2` attribute (not part of Student schema) has not been saved.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5901d1d830fa36f020e88ea7"),
    "name" : "extra fields",
    "event" : "from postman",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

[Mongoose schema save issue](https://github.com/florianholzapfel/express-restify-mongoose/issues/132)

Comment: how can we throw error if we have extra attribute apart from schema ??

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose wont save any field which is not present int the schema, you need to define a schema like -

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var productSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

saving product

```
var newProduct = new Product();

// set the user's local credentials
newProduct.title  = title;
newProduct.author = author;
newProduct.addintionalData = 'RandomData'; //wont save this data

newProduct.save();
```

Comment: how can we throw error if we had an extra attributes apart from schema defined ??, like for first level its work with **strict: 'throw'**, but it will not check nested level